# How to partially match a list in Python within a for loop?

Tags: python, list

```
final_list = [
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue'], 
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror'], 
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',], 
    ['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
]

criteria_list = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3]

cp = True
exclude_keyword = 'mirror'

for each_list in final_list:
    for check in criteria_list:
            if check in each_list and exclude_keyword not in each_list:
                cp = True
            else:        
                cp = False
    if cp == True:
        print(each_list)
```

I have this for loop which select lists from list of lists.  It is supposed to partially match the beginning elements of criteria_list and also exclude certain keywords elements that follow e.g the mirror element.

The problem being its not partially matching the beginning sequence of `criteria_list`. So essentially its returning `['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]` 
and `['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]` instead of just

`['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]` as the 'subsection' element does not match the sequence of criteria_list?

Comment: Does the order of element in `final_list` and `criteria_list` matter? Btw, in your code checks every element in `criteria_list` and if it contains in the inner list of `final_list`. So if the inner list is something like `['abc', 'def', 'section', 3]` then also it will return `True` which you may not want

Comment: Yes the order matters, I would prefer if it returns true only is the beginning sequence matches

Comment: So, the inner list must start with `'section'` , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_list = [
['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue'],
['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror'],
['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',],
['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
]
criteria_list = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3]
exclude_keyword = 'mirror'
for lista in final_list: # Loop through the main list
    if lista[:len(criteria_list)] == criteria_list and exclude_keyword not in lista: # checks if first elements are equal your criteria_list (if the order doesn't matter, this won't work). And checks if excluded_keyword is not inside this sublist.
        cp = True
        print(lista) # prints sublist.
    else:
        cp = False
```

This works if the order of the elements on criteria_list does matter.

I used list `slicing` to get only the first 4 elements of your final_list sublist and compare to your whole criteria list.

Comment: You mean when order **does** matter

Comment: Note that this is not a generic solution since the length on which the match is made is hardcoded...

Comment: Yes the order matter, the sequence of the criteria_list is what im looking for to match then anything else after that does not matter as long as exclude_keyword is not included

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers already changed that so it is not hardcoded anymore, thanks for advice.

Comment: @Darth if the order matters, try out my code, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You got output as you got because you never check for the equality of beginnings of your inner lists and `criteria_list`, you just check for the existence of elements of your `criteria_list` in each of inner ones.

Code that works:

```
final_list = [
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue'], 
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror'], 
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',], 
    ['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
]

criteria_list = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3]

cp = True
exclude_keyword = 'mirror'

for each_list in final_list:
    cp = False
    if exclude_keyword not in each_list and each_list:
        # you don't need to check for equality of the beginning 
        # if you got your exclude keyword
        for index, check in enumerate(criteria_list):
            if check == each_list[index]:
                cp = True
            else:        
                # if at some index equality fails then you should stop comparing
                cp = False
                break
    if cp == True:
        print(each_list)
```

Comment: You may want to do on thing, checking if `each_list` is non-empty

Comment: @kuro you are absolutely right(i would get `IndexError`)! I fixed the code. Thank you!